# Fullcalendar doesn't show first time bootstrap modal shows

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, fullcalendar

I have a modal with a `fullCalendar` in it.

`fullCalendar` doesn't show anything when modal shows up for the first time. If I close the modal and open it again `fullCalendar` shows with a bit delay in loading events. `.fullcalendar('render')` is not helping me in this case.

```
$("a.ScheduleOpen").click(function(e) {
        loadcalendar();
        //$('.Calendar').fullCalendar('refresh');
        $(".Calendar").fullCalendar('render');
        $(".Calendar").fullCalendar('gotoDate', new Date(y, m, d));
        $('#pnl_Schedule').modal('show');


    });
```

and I have the following code to handle the render part when modal is showing, still not working correctly:

```
$('#pnl_Schedule').on('shown.bs.modal', function() {
        $(".Calendar").fullCalendar('render');
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

For some reason, Fullcalendar will not display the calendar automatically when in the bootstrap modal. Only the today, left, and right buttons would display, and after clicking a button, the calendar would display fine after closing and reopening.

So, I got this working by clicking the today button after the modal is launched:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar();

$('#button').click(function() {
    window.setTimeout(clickToday, 200);
});

function clickToday() {
  $('.fc-button-today').click();
}
```

Here is a [working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ringstaff/Gbm89/12/).

EDIT:

Updated fiddle with suggested changes from @Ldom.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks.

I had the same problem (the calendar is inside a bootstrap Tab) and it would show up only when the page was resized.

I have tweaked your code so that it only "triggers" the display once. This way the user's navigation inside the calendar is maintained after tab clicks.

```
function clickToday() {
    if (!$("tr.fc-week").is(':visible'))
    {
      $('.fc-button-today').click();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use modal or tabs events :

```
$('#yourModal').on('shown.bs.modal', function(){
    $('#yourCalendar').fullCalendar({
        options: .....
    });
});
```

and destroy closing it if you need to change calendar or have some variables to it

```
$('#yourModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function(){
    $('#yourCalendar').fullCalendar('destroy');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

"Must have 50 reputation to add comment".

For anyone using the version 2.2.6 of FullCalendar, the "today" button name has changed from '.fc-button-today' to '.fc-today-button', so the one function to the answer now looks like this:

```
function clickToday() {
    $('.fc-today-button').click();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Something to add on ringstaff's answer:

Mine's today button is initially disabled, so the click function won't work for 'fc-today-button', so I used 'fc-timeGridWeek-button' instead (which is the default view), or any other button of your choice (dayGridMonth-button, timeGridDay-button, etc.)

And also, I have multiple modals&calendars, so I added a class for all the buttons. And here is my code.

```
$('.check-calendar-button').each(function() {
   $(this).click(function() {
       window.setTimeout(clickWeekButton, 200);
   });
});

function clickWeekButton() {
   $('.fc-timeGridWeek-button').click();
}
```